# Java Arraylist issue using Soap

Tags: java, soap

I'm a Java newbye.
I'm developing a soap service and trying to test using Soapui.

Everything is ok except for returning a list of data, which I get empty.

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "getOutputs", action = "getOutputs")
public ArrayList<String> getOutputs() {
    _log.info(">> getOutputs");
     ArrayList<String> stat = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        stat.add("prova");    
        _log.info("<< getOutputs. Adding prova. len is " + stat.size());         
    } catch (Exception e) {
        _log.error("getOutputs Error");
    }        

    return stat;
}
```

When I run SoapUi I don't get values even if in debug stat cointains one element. Also the log files says it cointains one element.
How can I solve the issue?

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <S:Body>
  <ns2:getOutputsResponse xmlns:ns2="http://xxxx.com/">
     <return/>
  </ns2:getOutputsResponse>
 </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried creating a service using JAX-WS web services API, released as part of Java EE 1. 6 and was able to get result:

Soap request

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://client/">
<env:Header/>
 <env:Body>
   <ns1:getOutputs/>
 </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

And got following response:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <S:Body>
   <ns0:getOutputsResponse xmlns:ns0="http://client/">
     <return>prova</return>
   </ns0:getOutputsResponse>
  </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```